Converting a subset of the dataframe into another dataframe
I have a pandas dataframe that looks like so
Index    Key    2010-01    2010-02    2010-03    ...    2020-12   
A/B/C    foo    0.23        0.44        0                2.1
A/B/C    bar    0.43        0.12        0.23             1.2
A/B/C    baz    0.25        0.23        0.2              2.5
P/Q/R    foo    0.31        0.41        0                2.4
P/Q/R    foo    0.33        0.54        0.5              4.2
P/Q/R    foo    0.93        0.64        0.99             6.5

The index is a multi-column index. "foo", "bar", "baz" are present for every index.
How do I convert this group of data into individual dataframes that looks like
# dataframe for A/B/C
index        foo        bar        baz
2010-01       0.23    0.43        0.25
2010-02       0.44    0.12        0.23
...
2020-12       2.1     1.2         2.5

Fairly new to pandas, so I tried converting data into dictionaries and working with it. So I have a solution that involves collecting the necessary values and then in the 2nd pass, converting them to their individual dataframes. The pseudo code was like this
# loop over the converted dictionary (as per keys)
For each key, create 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' with empty dicts;
    when encountering a row for 'foo', collect all values from col 2010-01 to 2020-12 as a list
    do the same for 'bar' and 'baz'. Add to the nested dict that is held by the given key
For the second pass, loop through each key
    take the nested dict and create a dataframe using the entire dict and the dates 2010-01 to 2020-12 as the index.

Is there a more panda-ish way to do this.
Is it possible to convert the group obtained by the index A/B/C and transpose it without incurring the hit of performance that comes with transpose?
The actual data in question may have upwards of 10000 such indices (>30k rows).

I believe your question needs additional clarification.  It is difficult to understand what you are trying to accomplish, given you sample data and expected output.  Please update your minimal reproducible example with a set of sample data, show the transformation that results in your expected output. See How to make good reproducible pandas examples for best practices related to Pandas questions

sounds like you are looking for pivot

Assuming "Index" the index, use groupby and transpose in a dictionary comprehension to create a dictionary of DataFrames:
out = {k: g.set_index('Key').T for k, g in df.groupby(level='Index')}

Output:
{'A/B/C': Key       foo   bar   baz
          2010-01  0.23  0.43  0.25
          2010-02  0.44  0.12  0.23
          2010-03  0.00  0.23  0.20
          2020-12  2.10  1.20  2.50,
 'P/Q/R': Key       foo   foo   foo
          2010-01  0.31  0.33  0.93
          2010-02  0.41  0.54  0.64
          2010-03  0.00  0.50  0.99
          2020-12  2.40  4.20  6.50}

Then you can access each DataFrame by key:
# out['A/B/C']

Key       foo   bar   baz
2010-01  0.23  0.43  0.25
2010-02  0.44  0.12  0.23
2010-03  0.00  0.23  0.20
2020-12  2.10  1.20  2.50

Alternatively, if you have the same (unique) keys (foo/bar/baz) for all groups, you could also use a pivot+stack:
tmp = df.reset_index().pivot(index='Index', columns='Key').stack(0)
out = dict(list(tmp.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
                   .groupby(tmp.index.get_level_values(0))))


Output:
{'A/B/C': Key       bar   baz   foo
          2010-01  0.43  0.25  0.23
          2010-02  0.12  0.23  0.44
          2010-03  0.23  0.20  0.00
          2020-12  1.20  2.50  2.10,
 'P/Q/R': Key       bar   baz   foo
          2010-01  0.33  0.93  0.31
          2010-02  0.54  0.64  0.41
          2010-03  0.50  0.99  0.00
          2020-12  4.20  6.50  2.40}


@dmayilyan this is a dictionary of DataFrames, the most logical way to store multiple DataFrames with keys.

Ah yes, you are right, my bad.

Assuming that df is the initial DataFrame I think you are looking for this:
import pandas as pd

for idx in df["Index"].unique():
   print(pd.pivot_table(df[df["Index"] == idx],
         values=["2010-01", "2010-02", "2010-03", "2020-12"],
         columns=["Key"]))

Of course values list can be derived from the df.columns.

This approach is not efficient, you will have to slice the full DataFrame again for each Index. Better use groupby for a unique operation.

Agree, depending on the load that's also an option.
